# Android device not working in FlashDevelop

Tags: android, air, flashdevelop

My Samsung Galaxy Gio s5660 doesn't seem to want to run my AS3 project from FlashDevelop.

I have followed the instructions in the mobile AS3 template and they were all completed successfully. I've also checked [photonstorms blog](http://www.photonstorm.com/archives/2431/creation-of-a-mobile-app-without-the-flash-ide-for-all-flashdevelop-lovers) but that didn't help.

I have turned on Settings > Application settings > development > USB Debugging

What happens is:

1. my project runs in desktop mode (displays 'hello world')
2. I change a value in 'run.bat' to run it on the device
3. builds successfully, but the 'waiting for flash player to connect to debugger' takes very long time and eventually times out.
4. The screen of the phone goes black (does not display 'hello world') in response to the successful build and in the android task manager I can see that it runs. The background color (black) is not correct either, it is set to white in the project.

I have been fiddling with settings but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried

- different version of air
- different resolutions
- using `goto android-debug` as well as `goto android-test` in the run.bar file
- stripping everything down to a simple hello world

android 2.3.3
samsung gt-s5660
flex 4.5.1 / air 3.0

edit: I have since found out my certificate wasn't 100% but it should be now (uninstalled all versions from the phone). And also now I'm getting 'force close' messages on every build on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question, my phone isn't on Adobe's certified smartphone list so there is probably no support for Flash on Galaxy Gio.

http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/smartphones.html#samsung